# How does opencv store matrix value in Gaussian mixture? In which order?

Tags: opencv, background-image, gaussian, subtraction, background-subtraction

I've searched the "bgfg_gaussmix2.cpp" code, it says in gaussian mixture model, it stores mixture weight (w), mean ( nchannels values ) and covariance for each gaussian mixture of each pixel background model. I want to know the order of its storage, for instance, is it "weight, mean, covariance", or " mean, covariance, weight", or something else? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are speeking about the gaussian mixture structure CvPBGMMGaussian, the storing order is

1. Weight
2. mean dimension 1
3. mean dimension 2
4. mean dimension 3
5. Variance

The three dimensions are packed in a float array.
Here is the definition  of this structure :

```
#define CV_BGFG_MOG2_NDMAX 3
typedef struct CvPBGMMGaussian
{
    float weight;
    float mean[CV_BGFG_MOG2_NDMAX];
    float variance;
}CvPBGMMGaussian
```

If you are not speeking about this structure, please be more precise in your question.

Comment: Hi Abarral, thank you very much for your answer! That is exactly what I want :)